# Wordpress overide 404 for private pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering how would I go about overiding wordpress's default 404 on private pages when not logged in? Had a look around at post-template.php however nothing I could change that made it work?

Comment: Do you really mean the '404 - Not found' page template or do you mean the 'You are not logged in and therefor cannot view this content' output?

Answer (score 4):

to create custom message for private pages

add this code to the top of your 404.php in your theme:

```
//Redirect if requested page is private
$page_requested = get_page_by_path($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$page_status = get_post_status( $page_requested->ID );
if( $page_status == 'private' ){
    wp_redirect( get_site_url().'/path/to/private/login' ); exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking, but it sounds like you want to create a custom 404 page and change that depending on whether someone is logged in or not.

To do that: create a `404.php` file and upload it to your theme directory (the same theme directory with the `header.php`, `footer.php`, `sidebar.php`, etc). Then, in the code, use this function:

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Code for logged in users
}
else {
    // Code for unknown users
}
```

That should do it it for you.

Sources: [Creating an Error 404 Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page), [Function - Is user logged in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)